# Capture audio from Android virtual device

Tags: android, audio, virtual, audio-recording

I would like to capture the audio from a Android Studio virtual device (a virtual android phone). I'm using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 on MacOs Monterey 12.6. I am using the virtual audio output from BlackHole. Strangely enough however, when I choose BlackHole as my sound output in MacOs, the audio of the system and all apps *except* for the android virtual device are output to the BlackHole virtual output. I verified that the audio is directed to the BlackHole channel by recording it using Audacity. The sound from the virtual phone however is still directed to the internal speakers and is thus not recorded.

**Some additional info**:
I also tried to use Soundflower instead of BlackHole, after installation (+ reboot) all sound of the virtual device was lost.

Using OBS I had no luck either, I don't have much experience with this program but I couldn't capture the audio that is also send to the speakers.

By Googling and searching here on StackOverflow I have not been able to find a similar problem that has been solved. Perhaps one exists but I couldn't find it. Most go into capturing audio from within the virtual android device or similar.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for programming related problems. If your issue is routing audio from the Android emulator (which appears to work) then it is an OS / app recording issue and I'm not sure if any stackexchange site would be appropriate, [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) are the closest I can think of but you may have better luck searching on mobile game streaming forums.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I somehow automatically posted my question here as most search results I found ended up here. I am open to solutions that require some programming in Android Studio but I have no prior experience. Perhaps my question can be migrated to Android Enthusiasts (thanks for your fora suggestions), I think that would be my best shot. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Still not sure if this question is appropriate for Android Enthusiasts since its more a Mac (M1 or Intel?) audio routing issue. I'm not even sure what is the goal with recording audio which is why I suggested looking into game streaming as audio recording is a core need. I would also search for third party Android Emulators like Nox or Bluestacks to see if they fit you need.

Comment: I have searched both fora using several keyword related to my problem to see which gives the most hits and could be the better choice, but I found no clear answer. But perhaps you are right and the Ask Different forum is more appropriate. I have an Intel MacBook and I indeed used to use BlueStacks for my purposes but I upgraded to version 4 after which it has become instable (opening the app results in a MacOS kernel overflow). I indeed also tried Nox but the sound instantly dies after starting an app. Thank you for your further suggestions, I'll try both another emulator and search game fora.